# Should be simple proof by induction

Tags: induction

I am trying to prove $n^2>2n+1$ for $k\ge 4$.

Intuitively this is true since $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(2+1/n)=2$.

Obviously $16>9$.

Assume $k^2>2k+1 \implies k^2+2k+2>2k+1+2k+2 \implies (k+1)^2+1>2(2k+1)+1$,

and $2(2k+1)+1>2(k+1)+1$ so $(k+1)^2+1>2(k+1)+1$, but now I am stuck.

I am not sure how to show this by induction...

Comment: Do you really _need_ induction ? ;-)

Comment: I thought my statement "Intuitively this is true since $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(2+1/n)=0$." was sufficient, but I was told otherwise

Comment: I mean, do you _have to_ do it using induction, or is any method OK ?

Comment: No I just need to prove the statement, I just thought induction was the way to go

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (2+1/n) = 2 + \lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n = 2+0=2$, not 0.

Comment: Thank you, obvious mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $k^2>2k+1$; then
$$
(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1>2k+1+2k+1=4k+2=2(k+1)+1+(2k-1)
$$
Can you say that $2k-1>0$?

---

Of course, you don't need induction at all, because this is a quadratic polynomial and we know that
$$
x^2-2x-1>0
$$
for $x>1+\sqrt{2}$ or $x<1-\sqrt{2}$. In particular, $n^2-2n-1>0$ for integer $n>2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $n^2-2n-1=(n-1)^2-2$ hence $n^2>2n+1$ iff $(n-1)^2>2$

Answer (score 1):

$n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$

$2n+1-1=2n$

Then $n+1>n$ and $n-1>2$ for $n\geq 4$.

Answer (score 0):

$n^{2}\gt {2n+1}$  holds for $n=4$ ;

If  possible  let  us  assume that  this  holds  upto  $n=k$  for  $k\ge 4$.

Now  we  see  $$(k+1)^{2}=(k^{2})+(2k+1) \gt (2k+1)+(2k+1)=4k+2$$

Now  if  we  can  show  that  $$4k+2\gt 2k+3=2(k+1)+1$$  then  we  are  done.

But  $$4k+2\gt 2k+3$$ 
iff  $$2k+2\gt 3$$
iff $$2k\gt 1$$  which  is  obviously  true  as  $$k\ge 4$$ .

Thus  we  see  $$4k+2\gt 2k+3$$ and  thus  proved  $$(k+1)^{2}\gt 2(k+1)+1$$
 So  $$n^{2}\gt 2n+1$$  holds  good  for  all  $n\ge 4$.